# How can I alert a web user that it's browser is not compatible with my application compiled to JS from Dart ?

Tags: browser, dart

As Dart web application compiled to JavaScript required a quite recent browser, it could be useful to advise web user with an old browser that they need to upgrade it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whith this package http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser_detect you should get the browser make and version.
This way you can check if the user has an officially supported browser, or a browser you have tested your app with.

If this is not what you want then it depends on what features you use. Some features work in many browsers other only in the officially supported browsers (or should work).
For some features there is an attribute to check if it is supported by the browser, for others you would need a workaround or hack.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start. 
Is there a way to get the _officially supported browsers_ according to the Dart version used ? I don't really want to hard code it.

Comment: That is a good question. I don't know. Here is an open bug with such a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15657